# Prove that, if $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges, then $\sum\limits_n \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that, if $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges, then $\sum\limits_n \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ diverges.

I believe it's true and even seems obvious, but once I tried to prove it I found it's not that trivial and I can't prove it rigorously.

Comment: Why do you think that it seems obvious?

Comment: @OpenBall I said that because I don't think $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ and $a_n$ can converge to $0$ at the same time. But I can't formalize it.

Comment: Think of the ratio test.

Comment: @Jose27 But isn't the ratio test only for $a_n > 0$? There is no such condition here.

Comment: @Jose27 ratio test is not necessarily conclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \to 0$, then there exists $N$ such that for $n\ge N$, $|a_n|<|a_{n+1}|$. As $|a_{N+1}|> |a_N|$, we get $|a_{N+1}|>0$, so for each $n\ge N+1$, $|a_n|\ge |a_{N+1}|>0$, contradicting $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there such a theorem that "If $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \to 0$, then there exists $N$ such that for $n\ge N$, $|a_n|<|a_{n+1}|$"?

Comment: That follows from the definition of limit (use $\epsilon=1$).

Comment: Sorry, I got it. Thanks!